# I want to make the path of my image dynamic

Tags: php, image, dynamic, path

I want a dynamic file path in my website. Currently, I store all files to `public_html/uploads` folder but I don't want to open the image as `example.com/uploads/logo.png` but instead, I want to open it as `example.com/username/name/logo.php`

I am storing all the image information on a table and want to generate a dynamic image/file path.

Comment: are you using a framework or just PHP? if you're just using PHP are you including a router in your application?

Comment: framework, actually Codeigniter